# Define the plot order of the x-axis, when using sort_values and pandas/pyplot

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I am plotting a bar chart of 'Time zone (UTC)' *Vs* 'Frequency', using value_counts() for column 'UTC_Hrs', in a pandas dataframe of twitter posts.

UTC_Hrs
-5.0
11.0
Nan
0.0

etc

I want the x axis to be ordered from, -11.0 to + 13.0, but I can't work out how to do it.

```
order = ["-11.0", "-10.0", "-9.0", "-8.0", "-7.0", "-6.0",  "-5.0", "-4.0",
         "-3.5", "-3.0", "0.0", "1.0" , "2.0","3.0", "4.0", "5.0",                
         "5.5","6.0","7.0", "8.0", "9.0", "10.0", "11.0", "13.0"]
```

I've found out how to order it as it occurs in the df by using, value_counts(sort=False):

```
df['UTC_Hrs'].value_counts(sort=False).plot(kind='bar')
```

I also found out how to pretend I had done it using ;-):

```
set_xticklabels(order)
```

I've tried other multiple variations inspired by other answers and the pandas docs but nothing has worked. The most complex thing and maybe closest I got was to to use a dictionary and mapping but couldn't work out how to call this on value_counts, thinking this was the wrong approach.

```
UTC_Hrs = df['UTC_Hrs'] 
mapping = {UTC_Hrs: i for i, UTC_Hrs in enumerate(order)}
key = df['UTC_Hrs'].map(mapping)
dfx = df.iloc[key.argsort()]
dfx.plot(kind='bar')??? value_counts by referencing dict?
```

Any help and advice much appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html) with intersection `order` and `s.index`, but is necessary same types - both `string`s or both `float`s:

```
s = df['UTC_Hrs'].astype(str).value_counts()
s.reindex(np.intersect1d(order, s.index)).plot.bar()
```

---

```
s = df['UTC_Hrs'].value_counts()
s.reindex(np.intersect1d(np.array(order).astype(float), s.index)).plot.bar()
```

Comment: thanks for coming to the rescue for the second day in a row, much appreciated